# Using streams to pipe input/output between *nix processes

Tags: c, linux, stream, exec, fork

I'm working on a fairly simple application in C. The end goal is to pipe the output from one process to in input of another in a *nix environment (yes, I am aware of the pipe() command and dup/dup2 but I'm trying to find away around using those commands). I was wondering if there is any way to connect the streams rather than using file descriptors (The systems aren't guaranteed to be POSIX compliant).

So basically I want to do something like this (pseudo-code)

```
pid = fork()

if pid == 0 
    // assign this process's stdin to the parents stdout.
    stdin = parent.stdout;
    exec() // launch new process that receives the parents stdout as stdin
    // child stuff....
else
    // parent stuff....
```

I know that it probably won't be as simple as just doing an assignment as above, but is there any way to do this using only streams? I tried looking around, but couldn't find anything..

Thanks!

Comment: You won't be able to avoid using pipes to connect the standard output of one process to the standard input of another (unless you count a Unix-domain socket as an alternative).

Comment: well darn. Okay, I was hoping I could be lazy. Thanks!

Comment: Just out of interest, what is wrong with pipe() or dup/2 ?

Comment: I read somewhere that mixing file descriptors and FILE*s wasn't the best idea. I have some code elsewhere in the application that uses freopen() on stdin to redirect input, so I'll probably end up changing that to use open and dup/dup2/pipe. :)

Answer (score 0):

sorry if I'm missing the point here but the whole philosophy of *nix is one program, one job. If you need a program to dump the contents of a program to the screen then you have the cat command. If the files too big and you need page breaks you pipe the output of cat to the more command:

cat myfile.txt | more

If you need to pipe between two terminal applications then you're meant to use the command line to do so:

myprog1 | myprog2

Obviously that's the philosophical approach, so if that doesn't help then can you clarify what you're trying to pipe and why you're trying to do it in process ?

Comment: Sorry Russ. I'm designing a light-weight terminal. And its one job is to run other jobs ;)

Comment: Aha, yes that would explain it :)